# Compile vim with python3 support in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, compile-vim

I'm used to Ubuntu and know how to compile and edit vim. But how can i compile vim with python3 support on windows ?

Prefer to do it from the terminal. But i don't mind if i need to do it with miniGW if thats a better option.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the instructions to build Vim on windows in the source file [`src/INSTALLpc.txt`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALLpc.txt).

More specifically in the section [8. Building with Python3 support](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALLpc.txt#L518-L546) you can read:

> ```
> 8. Building with Python3 support
> ================================
>
> For building with MSVC 2008 the "Windows Installer" from www.python.org
> works fine.  Python 3.6 is recommended.
>
> When building, you need to set the following variables at least:
>
>     PYTHON3:         Where Python3 is installed. E.g. C:\Python36
>     DYNAMIC_PYTHON3: Whether dynamic linking is used. Usually, set to yes.
>     PYTHON3_VER:     Python3 version. E.g. 36 for Python 3.6.X.
>
> E.g. When using MSVC (as one line):
>
>     nmake -f Make_mvc.mak
>         PYTHON3=C:\Python36 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes PYTHON3_VER=36
>
>
> When using msys2 and link with Python3 bundled with msys2 (as one line):
>
>     mingw32-make -f Make_ming.mak PYTHON3=c:/msys64/mingw64
>         PYTHON3_HOME=c:/msys64/mingw64
>         PYTHON3INC=-Ic:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.6m
>         DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes
>         PYTHON3_VER=36
>         DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=libpython3.6m.dll
>         STATIC_STDCPLUS=yes
>
> (This is for 64-bit builds. For 32-bit builds, replace mingw64 with mingw32.)
> ```

You may also want to look at the instructions in [`src/INSTALL.txt`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALL)

Comment: using `make`, as long as it's installed with MinGW, works as well. Also, in case anyone else gets stuck on the same problem: `make` needs to be executed in the `src` directory, not the root directory.